# Android Monitor Connectivity: I receive it twice

Tags: android, connection, broadcastreceiver

Some days ago I found a code in a Stackoverflow post to know when the connectivity of my device changes using a Broadcast Receiver. I adapted it to my application and it works, but everytime I turn on/off my internet connection, the onReceive method on my receiver is called twice. Why is that? My application works fine anyway, but I do some actions twice when once is enough.

This is my receiver:

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;

    Thread network_check = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(mContext)) {
                     // Do some stuff
            }
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MonitorInternetConnectivity", "onReceive");
        mContext = context;
        network_check.start();
    }
}
```

Network Helper class:

```
public class NetworkHelper {

    public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && canHit()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean canHit() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlConnection.connect();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

And I added this to my manifest (and the needed permissions):

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ConnectivityReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Everytime my connection changes the log shows "onReceive" twice. Why?

Thanks!

--------------- EDIT ---------------------

I add info about the intents received. Everytime the connectivity changes the two intents received are exactly the same.

When the device goes offline:

```
Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000010 cmp=com.pfc.app/.receivers.ConnectivityReceiver (has extras) }
Extras:
    NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
    noConnectivity: true
    inetCondition: 0
```

When the device goes online:

```
Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000010 cmp=pfc.dani.palou/.receivers.ConnectivityReceiver (has extras) }
Extras:
    NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
    inetCondition: 0
```

Comment: I edited the main post with the values in the intents.

Comment: do you register the BR in code ?

Comment: Had the same problem with CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED and gave up after several days. I just adapted my receiver to handle repeated broadcasts.